# R - Save Full Data Sets

Tags: r, for-loop, zoo

When i am using loop in R, for example

```
for (k in 1:length(bcd)) {
  print(window(abc,start = (as.Date(start[i,]),end = (as.Date(finish[i,]))))
}
```

The outcome will be the the full selected data.

However, if i want to save the selected data, it only remember the data corresponding to last loop counter.

```
for (k in 1:length(bcd)) {
  A = ???(window(abc,start = (as.Date(start[i,]),end = (as.Date(finish[i,]))))
}
```

What is the right function to use in "???" ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list is the most general type. You could for instance initialize "A":

```
A <-list()
for (k in 1:length(bcd)) {
  A[[k]] <- window(abc, start = (as.Date(start[i,]), end = (as.Date(finish[i,]))))
}
```

The pros use `seq_along()` instead of `1:length(.)`

If they are all the same number of columns but different numbers of rows then this might work:

```
do.call(rbind, A)   # since "A" is a list and the natural second argument to do.call
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work, the message says "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".

Comment: Change the `[k]` to `[[k]]` as this is a list.

Comment: But the outcome is separate data sets, how can i merge them into a single set?

Comment: I will fix the "[[" error. Actually those are not "separate datasets". The results will all be in the same list named "A". If you want to have a regular object like a dataframe you will need to assure us that the numbers of items in the windows will all be the same. Then we can simplify it. But until we know what your data is I was only going to provide a general solution.

Comment: What do u mean "If you want to have a regular object like a dataframe you will need to assure us that the numbers of items in the windows will all be the same'. Is it the number of total data included in the "A" or something else.I have sttached the summary of data whcih has two columns. It means the first subset has 6 rows.                                    summary(el_nino_1974_2000_all)
     Length Class Mode   
[1,] 12     zoo   numeric
[2,] 28     zoo   numeric
[3,] 34     zoo   numeric
[4,] 30     zoo   numeric
[5,] 12     zoo   numeric
[6,] 14     zoo   numeric
[7,] 28     zoo   numeric

Comment: That not a good representation. Better would be `dput` or `str` on your data. I suppose you could `rbind` them if they have all the same number of columns. See the main answer for a possible solution.